# MySql Database query for selecting random from each category?

Tags: mysql, database

```
Table Name : Employee
    +------+------+
    | name | dept |
    +------+------+
    | ABC  | 1    |
    | BCA  | 1    |
    | CYZ  | 2    |
    | CYZ  | 1    |
    | n... | n... |
    +------+------+

Table Name : Department
    +----+-----------+
    | id | dept_name |
    +----+-----------+
    | 1  | YYY       |
    | 2  | ZZZ       |
    | 3  | DDD       |
    +----+-----------+
```

I've to select 25 random entries against each dept_name from table `Employees`.
For eg. In table `Department` there are 10 entries with unique id.
so the result query will return `25(random) * 10 = 250` rows.

so far I'm working out this query but something is wrong with it.

```
Select * from Employee where dept in (Select id from Department) RAND;
```

Comment: Employe table does not have a id field

Comment: @Mayeulsgc sorry my bad. I've fixed the query

Comment: instead of RAND try `order by rand() limit 10`

Comment: you need to use `group_concat`

Comment: Pretend it's 15 (3 x 5) random rows say, and see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like below:

```
SELECT d.id, GROUP_CONCAT(name) employee_list FROM Department d JOIN (

    SELECT name FROM EMPLOYEE e WHERE d.id = e.dept ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 25
  ) v

  GROUP BY d.id
  LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to `GROUP_CONCAT` employees per department and then limit the list to 25 entries using `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`. Then join the limited values with employee table, like this:

```
SELECT e.* FROM Employee e
JOIN (
  SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(eid ORDER BY RAND()), ',', 25) EmpList
  FROM Employee
  GROUP BY dept
) t
ON FIND_IN_SET(e.eid, t.EmpList)
```

Working Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1bd04/1

Note: `GROUP_CONCAT` has a default limit of 1024 which can be increased.

---

Second option is to assign row numbers to all employees per department and then limit the result to 25 per department. This one does not uses *group_concat*.

```
SET @num := 0, @d_id := '';

SELECT eid, name, dept
FROM (
   SELECT e.*,
   @num := IF(@d_id = e.dept, @num + 1, 1) AS row_number,
   @d_id := e.dept AS dummy
   FROM (
     SELECT * FROM Employee ORDER BY dept, RAND()
   ) e
) t 
WHERE t.row_number <= 25
```

Working Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1bd04/22

Note: Both the fiddles above limits 2 employees per department for demo purposes.